# how to define a Maven Project as dependency for another Maven project for use in debugging in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, artifactory

I have 2 maven project that the main one uses the second one's jar as dependency. once I add the jar file as dependency via the artifactory server everything is good but the main problem is that I want to debug the main project and while tracing I want to be able to move to the code of the second project. please help how to do that in eclipse?

Comment: if you open both projects and (for instance) have the version set to `1.0.0-snapshot` (which should not exist in artifactory) and set your dependency accordingly,  eclipse will handle it all for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to have both projects opened in Eclipse.  The pom version number of the second project has to match what you specify in the version in the dependency in the first project.

Note that one comment on your post indicated to use a different version than would exist in artifactory.  This will work, but it is not necessary.  The versions DO have to match, but if your checked-out project in eclipse has the same version as what is in artifactory, it will use the local project instead of the artifact in artifactory.

Comment: Thank you. I tested it with simple maven projects created with "maven-archtype-quickstart" architecture type and it worked great. but there is one thing that I forgot to say in my question is that the main project I use, is a GWT-MAVEN project created by "gwt-maven-plugin", "net.ltgt.gwt.maven" so when I debug it I have to choose "debug as GWT Legacy Development mode with jetty". so if there is a little tip to get result I appreciate it else I need to open another question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy a `sources` jar as well, then you can use this in Eclipse for debugging.